# getting an error Comparison arguments must be compatible types: List<User>, List<Case__mdt>

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, custom-metadata

```
private static void whoCanClosetheCase() {   

      List <Case__mdt> FederationIdinCustomMetaDataType = [SELECT DeveloperName, Federation_ID__c FROM Case__mdt];
      List <User> CurrentUserFederationID = [SELECT Id, FederationIdentifier FROM User Where Id = : UserInfo.getUserID()];

    try{
         for(Case newCase : (List<Case>)Trigger.new) {
            //Check Case Status and Case Record Type 
              if(newCase.Status == 'Decision' && newCase.Status == 'Do not Proceed' && newCase.RecordTypeId == RecordFinderConstants.RECORDTYPEID_CLAIM ) {
                 if(CurrentUserFederationID <> FederationIdinCustomMetaDataType) {
                       newCase.AddError('The user is not allowed to close the case');
                  }   
          }  
      }

    catch(Exception ex){
            ApplicationLogUtility.logError('CaseTriggerHandler', 'whoCanClosetheCase', ex, ex.getMessage(), '', '', '', '', 0);
            ApplicationLogUtility.commitLog();
        }
       } 
  }
```

I am getting an error  Comparison arguments must be compatible types: List, List on this line of code if(CurrentUserFederationID <> FederationIdinCustomMetaDataType). Let me know what I have missed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi OneFourFour, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. The error tells you exactly what you did wrong. However, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please **[edit]** your post to add a more clear and thorough description.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the ID values out of the custom settings:

```
Set<String> fedIds = new Set<String>();
for(Case__mdt setting:[SELECT DeveloperName, Federation_ID__c FROM Case__mdt]) {
  fedIds.add(setting.Federation_Id__c);
}
for(Case newCase : (List<Case>)Trigger.new) {
    //Check Case Status and Case Record Type 
      if(newCase.Status == 'Decision' && newCase.Status == 'Do not Proceed' && newCase.RecordTypeId == RecordFinderConstants.RECORDTYPEID_CLAIM ) {
         if(!fedIds.contains(CurrentUserFederationID[0].FederationIdentifier)) {
               newCase.AddError('The user is not allowed to close the case');
          }   
     }  
}
```

As an aside, you really should consider just using a Custom Permission and a Validation Rule, which would be much simpler.

Comment: How will I know what is the content of the following using system.debug 1) fedIds.add(setting.Federation_Id__c); 
2) if(!fedIds.contains(CurrentUserFederationID[0].FederationIdentifier)) I am not sure is been missing here.                                                                                          3)It does not trigger the error message when I meet the condition.